# Perform index creation when new table is added to database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am coming from SQL Server to MySQL and there are tables that are created through a program that is run that need to be indexed. Last I read MySQL does not support DDL Triggers like SQL Server does.To me it would be easy to just perform the index creation in the create table statement then everyone's happy, but it is not possible for me to change the program. Is there any way to replicate the functionality of a DDL trigger in MySQL? If so what would that look like?

I've looked up event scheduler But I am unsure how that will work when there are hundreds of tables in a schema.

Comment: *"Is there any way to replicate the functionality of a DDL trigger in MySQL? If so what would that look like?"*  Most likely means in MySQL 8 to write your own [The ddl_rewriter Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ddl-rewriter.html) and in combination with [Query Rewrite Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ddl-rewriter.html)

Comment: You can add indexes after table creation with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX`.

Comment: I have came across using the rewrite plugin but I'm on version 5.6 and im unable to use it.